# How to restore OS X applications from a backup

Tags: macos, restore

I want to restore specific applications from a backup on OS X, to avoid having to reinstall them from scratch and possibly reconfigure my preferences. Should I also restore the `~/Library/Preferences` and `/Library/Preferences` or should I only restore `/Applications` and `~/Applications`? Are there any other things I need to restore to make sure my apps work correctly? That is, to make sure they aren't missing any needed libraries, frameworks, or other resource files that may have been installed elsewhere?

Comment: Applications store user data and preferences in the /Library/ Preferences: how do you mean, should you restore it? :)

Comment: I feel like this is a valid and important question and shouldn't have been closed. I've edited it to make it more clear, and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

If you're restoring sandboxed apps you bought from the App Store, you might want to restore their sandboxes.

If you're restoring non-sandboxed apps, especially apps that are installed via an installer rather than a drag-copy, or apps that prompt you for an admin password on first run, it's hard to know what files they may have sprinkled throughout places like `/Library`, `/var`, and `/etc`.

`[~]/Library/Preferences` is probably the least of your concern, because those can usually be recreated with a visit to the application's preferences window. They usually don't keep the program from running correctly, unless an app happens to keep a license key file there.

Comment: how do I restore a sandbox? is that just .app file with the contents?

Comment: Do apps use any type of manifest listing dependent modules/files?

Comment: @Coltrane58 The sandboxes are in `~/Library/Containers` for each user. To the best of my knowledge, apps don't have any kind of manifest that tells what other files they might use that got installed elsewhere. If your app came as a `.pkg` file to be installed by OS X's built-in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app`, then that .pkg file would have a BOM (Bill Of Materials) file listing what files get installed where. However, if your app prompts the user for admin credentials on the first launch and then installs stuff around, there's not easy way to know what it did.